# How to generate delta differences between old and new values of a set of attributes?

Tags: java, diff, delta

I have a requirement to generate the delta difference between old and new values for set of attributes. For each attribute we have to show old value, new value and the delta (what is added newly in new value in green color, removed text in red) in html format. Possible attribute types are String, number, decimal, list, Clob. This has to be generated in backend layer which is java. Are there any libraries available for this purpose?

Comment: Yes there can be libraries out there but it will only complicate what you are trying to achieve. From my understanding Delta is simply the difference between 2 value in your case the difference between the old value and the new value then print out the values new value in green, old value in red. Also this whole post looks like a class assignment

Comment: It is not a class assignment. it is a real use case. We were able to achieve this from front end but we have APIs which can directly modify.